# Can I turn a manifested card face up during the declare blockers step?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I attack with a manifested (face down) card and my opponent declares blockers, is priority then passed to me so I can turn it face up for its mana cost, or must I turn it up after declaring attackers?

Comment: Are you just asking about whether you get priority during Declare Blockers or is there something specific about Manifest you want to know?

Comment: To manifest a card is to put it into play face down; flipping it up is simply called turning it face up.

Comment: @Jefromi The word "flip" means something totally different. See [all of these cards from Kamigawa Block](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[flip]&format=[%22Kamigawa%20Block%22]).

Comment: @Rainbolt Okay, I suppose I should have said "turning it face up is called turning it face up" - the point was that it's *not* called manifesting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you get priority during the Declare Blockers step. [Rule 509](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Declare_Blockers_Step) describes how the Declare Blockers step progresses, and rule 509.5 says

> Fifth, the active player gets priority. Players may cast spells and activate abilities.

You can turn a manifested card face up any time you have priority, so that includes during the Declare Blockers phase. Rule 701.31b says

> Any time you have priority, you may turn a manifested permanent you control face up. This is a special action that doesn't use the stack (see rule 115.2b). To do this, show all players that the card representing that permanent is a creature card and what its mana cost is, pay that cost, then turn the permanent face up.